# str_c to build a quotation-wrapped comma separated vector

Tags: r, stringr

`iris %>% select(where(is.numeric)) %>% colnames() %>% str_c(., collapse = '","')`

Output: "Sepal.Length","Sepal.Width","Petal.Length","Petal.Width"
It gets me close to what I want (I don't really care about the space missing after the comma) but I can't remove the backslash afterwards with `str_remove_all` because it doesn't recognize the escaped backslash

Ideal: "Sepal.Length","Sepal.Width","Petal.Length","Petal.Width"

`iris %>% select(where(is.numeric)) %>% colnames() %>% str_c(., collapse = '",') str_remove_all(., "\\")`

output: `Error in stri_replace_all_regex(string, pattern, fix_replacement(replacement),  :  Unrecognized backslash escape sequence in pattern. (U_REGEX_BAD_ESCAPE_SEQUENCE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use :

```
library(dplyr)

iris %>% 
      select(where(is.numeric)) %>% 
      colnames() %>% 
      sprintf('"%s"', .) %>%
      toString()

#[1] "\"Sepal.Length\", \"Sepal.Width\", \"Petal.Length\", \"Petal.Width\""
```

The backslashes are not part of actual string, that is how R displays double quotes. To see the actual string you can use `cat` :

```
iris %>% 
      select(where(is.numeric)) %>% 
      colnames() %>% 
      sprintf('"%s"', .) %>%
      toString() %>% 
      cat

#"Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width"
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain what "%s" does in sprintf() for curiousity's sake?

Comment: Depending on the type of data that we are passing in `sprintf` we use the symbol. `%s` is for strings, `%d` for numeric, `%f` for floats and so on.